# Xml document download and deserialization

Tags: c#

I have the following Xml document stucture:

```
<Cube>
    <Cube time="2016-07-22">
     <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.1014"/>
     <Cube currency="JPY" rate="116.86"/>
     <Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558"/>
     <Cube currency="CZK" rate="27.023"/>
   </Cube>
</Cube>
```

How can I deserialize it into object?

**UPDATE**
I've end up with the following method which uses LINQ to XML to walk through the downloaded Xml

```
public async Task<List<DailyRates>> ParseRates()
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        var dailyRates = new List<DailyRates>();
        var task = new Task<List<DailyRates>>(() =>
        {
            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                result = webClient.DownloadString(_url);
            }
            var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(result);
            var timeCubes =
                xDocument.Elements()
                    .First()
                    .Elements()
                    .Where(el => el.Name.LocalName == "Cube")
                    .SelectMany(c => c.Elements());
            foreach (var timeCube in timeCubes)
            {
                var dailyRate = new DailyRates()
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Parse(timeCube.Attribute("time").Value),
                    CurrencyRates = (from xElement in timeCube.Elements()
                        select new CurrencyRate()
                        {
                            CurrencyName = xElement.Attribute("currency").Value,
                            Rate = Double.Parse(xElement.Attribute("rate").Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                        }).ToList()
                };
                dailyRates.Add(dailyRate);
            }
            return dailyRates;
        });
        task.Start();
        return await task;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Personally I'd just use LINQ to XML. It's a bit odd that you've got the same element name for three different "kinds" of value: one that's just a container, one that's a container with a time, and one with a currency and rate...

Comment: For now I have only tried to use regular XmlSerializer but havent got any result with this. Yup, this namings of elements confusing me a lot, but it's an Xml from external resource so I can't do anything with it. Thanks for advice, will try to use LINQ to XML.